# How to accomplish google oauth authentication using nancy api and angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, api, oauth, google-api, nancy

I have been looking around for this issue and haven't found anything yet.

I want to create a webapp that requests offline access to google api, and the my main concern is that I'm using angular as a front-end and I'm consuming a api created in nancy.

I have been able to get access but only for a couple of hours, but I need the user to grand offline access to the app because it's going to have a task running every amount of time needed.

Have anyone already accomplish this one? Tried? Experience? I've tried to call the google oauth api to request the token but it returns 405 method not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Simpleauthentication](https://github.com/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication), which has Nancy specific [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy.SimpleAuthentication/). Just follow the [instruction to set ip SimpleAuthentication in a Nancy app](https://github.com/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication/wiki/NancyFX-Automatic-Setup).

Comment: Hi Christian, sorry for late response. That looks good, I will test this and let you know by monday.

Comment: Versions > 0.3.14 does not fetch AccessTokenSecret from Twitter and latest versions i.e 0.6 conflicts with `Nancy.Authentication.Forms` when trying to validate user with google

Answer (score 0):

I've never used nancy. But in general, your OAUTH concerns should be handled server-side. The user validates against the google oauth, that google oauth flow returns to the back-end server, and the back-end server gives up a key, cookie, or something like that, which your front-end now uses in its request.

That's at least how I handle it. I use a token-based scheme for all my $http requests from my back-end API, which returns 401 if there's no valid token on the request and 403 if there is a token, but that token doesn't authorize that resource. I stuck a httpProvider interceptor in angular that, in the event of a 401, initiates client-side login flow.

Specifically, the token just is a randomly generated series of bits turned into hexadecimal, and then I stash it in redis as a key whose value is the user_id associated with this login.

Of course all of this requires a real https stack to be secure, since I'm just pushing what amount to plain-text one-time keys around, but that's about all you can do about that.

Comment: Hi @pfooti I think you are right. I was able to handle it via server side.